# Predicate that checks whether a list contains duplicates

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list and returns true if it contains a duplicate entry and false otherwise. I know I'm supposed to use **member**.  Here is my attempt so far (which fails):

```
(defun dupl (lst)
  (if (null lst) '())
  (if ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (dupes (cdr lst))))
    (t (dupl (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: what problem does your code have? Write test cases and show the problem with input and output! How does the code fail and where? Should we guess the problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my two cents on efficiency. If you use `memberp` to test for duplicates, then you're comparing each element to each other element and the complexity is O(N^2). Joshua in his answer suggested using a hash table to test for duplicates, which will give a linear running time O(N) at the expense of space. It might also be slower for smaller lists. Finally, if your list can be sorted, then you should get O(N.log(N)) as coredump- mentions. Here is an example that tests for duplicates in *numeric* lists using `sort`. (This is a destructive function.)

```
(defun duplicatesp (list)
  (mapl (lambda (cdr) (if (eql (first cdr) (second cdr))
                          (return-from duplicatesp T)))
   (sort list '<)) nil)
```

**UPDATE**

Out of curiosity, I measured the performance of the suggested answers for worst-case scenarios (almost no duplicates). So, 1 mln tries of lists of 10 elements:

- using `member` (Jan's answer): 1.139 seconds;
- using `hash-table` (Joshua's answer): 1.436 seconds;
- using `sort` (see above, but with first copying the list): 1.484 seconds.

So, no difference with small lists. Interestingly, using a hash table has some penalty but it is very small. Let's try 1000 tries of lists of 1000 elements:

- using `member`: 9.968 seconds;
- using `hash-table`: 0.234 seconds;
- using `sort`: 0.390 seconds.

As expected, using `member` has higher complexity. The difference between sorting and hashing is non-visible at this list size. Let's do 10 tries of lists of 1,000,000 elements:

- using `hash-table`: 3.214 seconds;
- using `sort`: 9.296 seconds.

So, `sort` is still quite good but is slowing down. Here is a simple code I used to profile the functions:

```
(defun random-list (length)
  (loop for i from 0 below length collecting
       (random (expt 10 10))))

(defun random-collection (length tries)
  (loop for i from 0 below tries collecting
       (random-list length)))

(defun test-duplicates (function &key length tries)
  (let ((rc (random-collection length tries)))
    (time (mapc function rc))
    nil))

(test-duplicates #'dp_hash :length 1000000 :tries 10)
;etc.
```

Comment: Note that I used hash tables not primarily for the speed (though that's an important factor), but because it made it easy to return a more useful result.  In my answer, I iterated through the entire list.  It's probably a micro optimization, but for the hash table approach, a "fairer" comparison would be to stop after the first duplicate is found.

Comment: Of course, a **sort** based should probably be copying the list, too, since checking for duplicates really isn't something that would need to modify the structure of the list.

Comment: I was testing worst case scenarii with no duplicates, so it should not matter that the hash variant does not return on first possibility. Copying the list is O(N), so it does not change the complexity. But I've updated the timing accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few problems in your code.

- The first `if` should use `return-from` to actually return the value. It's also better to use `nil` instead of `'()`.
- In the second `if` you are trying to use `cond` syntax.
- I'm not even sure what you were trying to achieve with the `cons`, but that doesn't seem necessary.

With these fixed, your code would look like this:

```
(defun dupl (lst)
  (if (null lst) (return-from dupl nil))
  (if (member (car lst) (cdr lst)) 
      t
      (dupl (cdr lst))))
```

It might be cleaner to turn the two `if`s into a single `cond`:

```
(defun dupl (lst)
  (cond ((null lst) nil)
        ((member (car lst) (cdr lst)) t)
        (t (dupl (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: I think "might be" is an understatement ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If a function returns a boolean, it is likely to be expressible as a boolean expression. The following quadratic version is a possible implementation:

```
(defun duplicatesp (list &key (test #'eql))
  (and list
       (or (member (first list) (rest list) :test test)
           (duplicatesp (rest list) :test test))))
```

The lazy-programmer version that follows also does the trick:

```
(defun duplicatesp (list)
  (not (equal (remove-duplicates list) list)))
```

You could also sort a copy of your list first for a better time complexity of O(n.log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Many functions in Common Lisp uses [*generalized booleans*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_g.htm#generalized_boolean), according to which **nil** (the empty list) is *false*, and everything else is *true*:

> #### [Type BOOLEAN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_ban.htm)
>
> … Conditional operations, such as if, permit the use of generalized
>   booleans, not just booleans; any non-nil value, not just t, counts as
>   true for a generalized boolean. However, as a matter of convention,
>   the symbol t is considered the canonical value to use even for a
>   generalized boolean when no better choice presents itself.

Note the remark that **t** is used "when no better choice presents itself."  It's often helpful to make functions that return a generalized boolean return some other piece of useful information as the true value.  For instance, [**member**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) returns the tail of the list whose first element is the element being checked for membership.  In this case, it might be useful to return an association list mapping duplicated elements to the number of times that they appear in the list.

Here's an approach that does that.  It first iterates through the list, building a hash table of the unique (as per [**test** and **key** arguments](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/17_ba.htm)) elements of the list, mapping each one to the number of times it appears.  Then, a pass through the hash table is used to build an association list of all the elements that appear more than once.

```
(defun contains-duplicates (list &key (test 'eql) (key 'identity))
  "Returns an association list mapping duplicated elements to the
number of times that they appear in LIST.  TEST is a comparison
operator used to determine whether two elements are the same, and must
be acceptable as a test argument to MAKE-HASH-TABLE.  KEY is used to
extract a value from the elements of LIST, and the extracted values
are compared and returned in the result."
  (let ((table (make-hash-table :test test))
        (result '()))
    (dolist (x list)
      (incf (gethash (funcall key x) table 0)))
    (maphash #'(lambda (key count)
                 (unless (eql 1 count)
                   (push (cons key count) result)))
             table)
    result))
```

```
(contains-duplicates '(1 1 2 3 4 4 4))
;;=> ((4 . 3) (1 . 2))

(contains-duplicates '(1 2 3 4)) ; no duplicates 
;;=> NIL

(contains-duplicates '("A" "a" b a) :test 'equal :key 'string)
;;=> (("A" . 2))

(contains-duplicates '("A" "a" b a) :test 'equal :key 'string) ; "A" ~ a, but not "a"
;;=> (("A" . 2))

(contains-duplicates '("A" "a" b a) :test 'equalp :key 'string) ; "A" ~ "a" ~ a
;;=> (("A" . 3))

(contains-duplicates '(1 2 3 5) :key 'evenp) ; two even elements
;;=> ((NIL . 2))
```